# Create Variable Name When Defining A Function

Tags: python, function, loops, for-loop

I am working in Python trying to write a function using a list of variables.
Here is the data I am working with:

```
material_list=['leather', 'canvas', 'nylon']

def materialz(MAT):

   MAT=support.loc[(material==MAT)].sum()

for i in enumerate(material_list):

   materialz(i)
```

What I am looking for is to pass in each of the items in the list to the function to produce global variables.

```
leather=

canvas=

nylon=
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Consider a shared `dict` instead!

Comment: `materials = {m: support.loc[(material==m)].sum() for m in material_list}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a dictionary and dynamically assign the key-value pairs there. Such as:

```
material_list=['leather', 'canvas', 'nylon']
material_dict={}
for i in enumerate(material_list):
    material_dict[i]=value #Where i would be the key and value the value in the key-value pair
```

Comment: Thank you for suggesting a dictionary. I was wondering if I could create variables but this will work for me.

Answer (score -2):

you can use exec

```
var = 'hello'
```

output = hello

```
exec('var = "world"')
print(var)
```

output = world

Comment: Using `exec()` is often a safety hazard and creating variables on-the-fly is generally considered a bad idea, see [Why you don't want to dynamically create variables](https://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html).